# using by and mapply together

Tags: r, mapply

Hi I am trying to get the ICC for value conditional on a set of factor levels.  For example:

```
usr1<-data.frame(a1=1:5,a2=11:15,a3=21:25,bin=factor(c("a","b","a","a","b")))
usr2<-data.frame(a1=2:6,a2=12:16,a3=32:36)
```

I would like the ICC of a1, a2, and a3 where the bin is a and b.  Before conditioning on the factor, I used mapply

```
mapply(function(x,y){z<-data.frame(x,y);icc(z,model="t",type="a")},usr1[,-4],usr2)
```

I cannot figure out how to wrap this with by to do this for each level of the factor.

```
mapply(function(x,y){z<-data.frame(x,y);icc(z,model="t",type="a")},usr1[c(1,3,4),-4],usr2[c(1,3,4),])
```

should give you the correct answer for level "a"
and

```
mapply(function(x,y){z<-data.frame(x,y);icc(z,model="t",type="a")},usr1[c(2,5),-4],usr2[c(2,5),])
```

should give you the correct answer for level "b".

This is a very simplified version of my problem where I have to calculate over 200 ICC's for 20 levels.  I don't know in advance which rows have which factors, except for the fact I have it in the data.frame.
Thank you

*EDIT*

The expected output would be like....

```
usr1$bin:a
           a1          a2          a3          
subjects   3           3           3           
raters     2           2           2           
model      "twoway"    "twoway"    "twoway"    
type       "agreement" "agreement" "agreement" 
unit       "single"    "single"    "single"    
icc.name   "ICC(A,1)"  "ICC(A,1)"  "ICC(A,1)"  
value      0.8235294   0.8235294   0.03713528  
r0         0           0           0           
Fvalue     -5.2542e+15 -5.2542e+15 1.094625e+14
df1        2           2           2           
df2        1           1           1           
p.value    1           1           6.758531e-08
conf.level 0.95        0.95        0.95        
lbound     0.005803109 0.005803109 4.823719e-05
ubound     0.9944658   0.9944658   0.5976005   
------------------------------------------------------
usr1$bin:b
           a1          a2          a3          
subjects   2           2           2           
raters     2           2           2           
model      "twoway"    "twoway"    "twoway"    
type       "agreement" "agreement" "agreement" 
unit       "single"    "single"    "single"    
icc.name   "ICC(A,1)"  "ICC(A,1)"  "ICC(A,1)"  
value      0.9         0.9         0.06923077  
r0         0           0           0           
Fvalue     Inf         Inf         Inf         
df1        1           1           1           
df2        1           1           1           
p.value    0           0           0           
conf.level 0.95        0.95        0.95        
lbound     0.01370303  0.01370303  0.0001148084
ubound     0.9998285   0.9998285   0.9796676
```

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap `lapply` for the different `bin`:

```
res<-lapply(unique(usr1$bin),function(x){  
  mapply(function(x,y){z<-data.frame(x,y);icc(z,model="t",type="a")},usr1[usr1$bin==x,-4],usr2[usr1$bin==x,])
})
names(res)<-unique(usr1$bin)
```

Comment: Thanks @fishtank I got stuck on using by that I did not think of lapply.